# Remove nodes continuity in function plot - Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

So i have this graph

[image: A plot example]

What i want is to delete those lines that is connecting the nodes. In other words, i want to make the function discontinuous. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage} % Package to use full page
\usepackage{parskip} % Package to tweak paragraph skipping
\usepackage{tikz} % Package for drawing
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{tiempos-ej3.csv}{\table}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel= $n$,
  ylabel=  $\frac{\text{Tiempo}}{n^2 log(n)}$ (ns), 
  ymax = 2*(10^4)]
\addplot+[thin,mark size=1pt] table[x = cant_ejes, y expr = {\thisrow{ns_rutas_vacias}/(\thisrow{cant_ejes}^2)*log2(\thisrow{cant_ejes})} , col sep=comma]{\table};
\addlegendentry{G vac\'{i}o}

`\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

The data i'm using (*tiempos-ej3.csv*):

```
cant_ejes, ns_rutas_completas, ns_rutas_vacias, ns_rutas_esparso_conexo, ns_rutas_esparso_disconexo, ns_rutas_denso_conexo, ns_rutas_denso_disconexo
3, 15109, 13161, 12260, 12340, 10934, 10745
4, 18513, 19096, 20259, 20242, 20091, 23546
5, 25926, 23830, 25166, 24425, 28358, 25901
6, 32842, 32804, 31192, 30337, 33519, 36024
7, 47523, 39249, 49199, 38813, 46590, 49289
8, 63149, 48312, 50708, 49158, 58302, 55832
9, 78487, 59447, 62883, 62028, 74124, 85009
10, 84284, 75011, 75005, 81518, 84359, 95588
11, 114197, 90523, 97204, 84448, 100826, 95811
12, 130247, 114882, 110839, 108813, 123487, 133510
13, 151885, 117559, 125032, 110552, 143293, 141648
14, 183447, 150974, 170673, 118187, 189117, 178468
15, 191086, 193268, 167568, 148669, 202532, 208375
16, 230066, 224609, 211090, 207802, 264420, 244803
17, 290928, 235203, 223133, 222825, 281324, 261841
18, 295962, 228604, 241625, 312163, 249293, 308734
19, 385266, 273003, 225277, 253495, 318229, 285187
20, 420176, 394646, 301843, 225683, 342848, 382659
21, 384356, 372527, 294318, 301941, 401165, 377724
22, 467103, 403543, 396645, 323385, 427804, 483534
23, 460606, 457728, 382173, 342659, 519994, 529115
24, 542626, 555261, 483915, 371078, 496230, 531801
25, 632575, 487439, 601581, 448299, 589256, 609845
26, 720005, 578490, 562307, 534066, 825475, 636652
27, 747257, 633856, 674922, 536209, 787483, 647211
28, 746051, 664636, 640455, 610362, 894280, 781946
29, 769671, 775363, 675715, 634716, 845139, 861882
30, 1088255, 782655, 890112, 653516, 921207, 916707
31, 1054147, 852580, 911578, 785632, 1087515, 881952
32, 971451, 836084, 862630, 770111, 959529, 1007144
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Look at scatter plots in the manual.

Comment: `\begin{axis}[only markers,...]`

Comment: @HenriMenke `only marks`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Right. Sorry about that, i've already updated missing info =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide data, so I used random points.  As indicated in the comments add `only marks` to the axis specification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    only marks,
    xlabel=$n$,
    ylabel=$\frac{\text{Tiempo}}{n^2 log(n)}$ (ns), 
    ymax = 2*(10^4)]
    \addplot+[thin,mark size=1pt,samples=300] {1.9e4*rnd};
    \addlegendentry{G vac\'{i}o}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]